# LaTeX Error: File `subfiles.sty' not found

Tags: packages, texlive, compiling, subfiles

I'm using `pdflatex` to compile my `.tex` files and I'm new on this.

I have this package that uses subfiles, but I can't compile because of this error:

```
LaTeX Error: File `subfiles.sty' not found.
```

I have already installed `texlive-full` and all other packages that I think could be the solution, also I run `texhash` and didn't work.

How can I overcome this error?
Where are the package files? Can I download a `subfiles.sty` directly there?

Comment: It should be in `texlive-latex-extra` if you're on Ubuntu/Debian. But only for TeX Live 2012, not in the 2009 release that you may have.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, it is important to know how did you install TexLive:

- As a package from your linux distribution.

  - What distribution?
  - What version of TexLive?
- Directly from [TexLive](http://www.tug.org/texlive/acquire.html).

My installation of TexLive is the second one, TexLive 2012, and the file `subfiles.sty` is located at:

```
$TEXLIVE_HOME/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.sty
```

So, if you installed from your distribution, you have two options:

- If using Debian (or Debian based distros), install `texlive-latex-extra` as pointed out by @egreg.
- If using other distros, try to search a good match with the respectiv package manager.
- If you prefer to have a more up-to-date LaTeX distribution, think about installing TexLive2012 from the link above.

**UPDATE 1**:

As you are using Linux Mint, this problem is very strange, because if you execute in a terminal:

```
apt-cache show texlive-latex-extra
```

you can find `subfile` package in the list.

**UPDATE 2**:

According to [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/sid/all/texlive-latex-extra/filelist), the location of `subfiles.sty` should be this:

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfiles/subfiles.cls
```

---

### Not your desired solution, but my humble advice:

I use Linux Mint debian edition at home (and Debian at work), but on both systems I have TexLive2012 installed by hand, in a custom directory, so I cannot tell you what happens with the distro packages.

Haven't you thought about installing TexLive directly with `install-tl`?:

- Download [install-tl](http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet/install-tl-unx.tar.gz) and unpack it.
- Follow the instructions at [TeX Live - Quick install](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

I hope this can help.

Comment: I'm using Linux Mint which is Debian derived. I have installed texlive with the package manager (synaptics). The package `texlive-latex-extra` is already installed. I couldn't find my "$TEXLIVE_HOME"

Comment: Please read my update above. About `TEXLIVE_HOME`, it's just a way to reference to the location where TexLive is installed. In your case, as you're using distro packages, it should be something similar to `/usr/share/texlive` in most cases.

Comment: Thanks by the fast response. 
Using `apt-cache show texlive-latex-extra` didn't show subfile package (there is lots of packages, but not subfile). The packages are in slightly different location `/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/$PACKAGE_FOLDER` but no subfiles there either. Never mind the original question, I will follow your advice and do a hard-hand install.

Comment: What version of LinuxMint Debian edition are you using?

Comment: Linux Mint 13 (Maya) Cinnamon 64-bit

Comment: Yours is based in Ubuntu then, not directly in Debian.

Comment: Yes, but Ubuntu is also Debian based

Comment: I can only say: that was an abuse of transitivity. Anyway, I hope your installation of TexLive is doing fine.

Answer (score 1):

First, check whether your file is installed

```
locate subfiles.sty
```

(or `find | grep subfiles.sty` from your TeX directory).

If that is absent, install the package (via `tlmgr` or your system's installer). If that is present, then the problem is that `LaTeX` can't find that.

Path searches in `LaTeX` are done by [kpathsea](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html). One can add paths to the search path:

```
export TEXINPUTS=.:/opt/tex/cur//
```

, where two slashes mean [subdirectory expansion](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Subdirectory-expansion).

Another option is to create a [filename database](https://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#Filename-database)

```
texhash /opt/tex/cur
```

(or `mktexlsr` depending on your system). Then add that path to your `TEXMFDBS` variable:

```
export TEXMFDBS=/opt/tex/cur
```

Note that database search works much faster than path expansion:

```
$ /bin/time kpsewhich standalone.cls
...
0.42user 0.05system 0:00.48elapsed 99%CPU 

$ export TEXMFDBS=/opt/tex/cur
$ /bin/time kpsewhich standalone.cls
...
0.05user 0.00system 0:00.06elapsed 98%CPU
```

Comment: It's a pity that this is not written in TeXLive installation manuals, but scattered on TUG site.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it with

```
sudo tlmgr install subfiles
```